# Display names are cut off on the Top Apps and Top Scripts pages

Tags: bug, design, stackapps

Using Firefox 51.0.1 on Windows 10. See the screenshot below:

> [image: screenshot of the Top Apps page]

Comment: Same on Chrome macOS